# Change Outlook 2007 Send Options Programatically

Tags: c#, interop, outlook, contacts, email-formats

We have several customers who have difficulty receiving PDF's from us via BPOS.  In order to correct the problem, we have to change their "Send Options" from Outlook to Plain Text.  What I would like to do is automate this so we don't have to manually do this to each contact for each user.
I written code where I can get to the contact in question, but I don't see where to set this particular setting. 
Can anybody point me in the right direction as to where this property may be?

Thanks, 
Eric Gurney

Comment: Have you had any chance to look at this?

Answer (score 0):

I don't see any way to do this programmatically in Outlook. Unfortunately, not everything in Outlook is scriptable.

The best you can do is provide a script that tells the local user which recipients can be manually changed. If the AddressEntry.Type Property is `SMTP` then it can be changed to plain text. This code is VBA but should be easy to convert to C#.

```
Sub CheckSMTP()

  Dim ns As Outlook.NameSpace
  Dim al As Outlook.AddressList
  Dim aes As Outlook.AddressEntries
  Dim ae As Outlook.AddressEntry
  Dim newae As Outlook.AddressEntry

  Set ns = session
  Set al = ns.AddressLists("Contacts")
  Set aes = al.AddressEntries

  For Each ae In aes
    Debug.Print ae.Address & " - " & ae.Type
  Next ae
End Sub
```